# Map doesn't show up in CARTOframes

Tags: python, carto, cartoframes

I'm new in Carto. I have been trying to figure out how Maps are used, I tried this code that is in the web; however the map is never displayed.

```
from cartoframes.auth import set_default_credentials, Credentials, get_default_credentials
from cartoframes.viz import Map, Layer

set_default_credentials('cartoframes')
current_creds = get_default_credentials()

Map([Layer('countries')])
```

Comment: I think that you need put your credentials https://carto.com/developers/cartoframes/reference/#cartoframes-auth-set_default_credentials

Comment: My credentials didn't work in my python script. However, I read that the problem is that carto is optimized for jupyter notebook so I tried there and it worked!

Comment: If you have the solution to your problem (running your code in a jupyter notebook) please answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was running my code in a Jupyter notebook, as it is optimized for them